# What is the probability that the number of zeros of a binary sequence with length $m$ is at least $q$?

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, limits

For a practical problem for a project (not educational) for a friend I need your help.

- We have a sequence $b$ of $m$ binary values: $$b_1,...,b_m $$ **Update: We have sequence b'of m' hexadecimal ($b_i$=0,1,...15) values: $$b_1,...b'_m$$**
- $n<m$ of them have value 1, the other $m-n$ elements have value 0

  **$n'<m'$ of them don't have value 0 (but 1-15), the other $(m'-n')$ elements have value 0**
- We choose $x<m$ elements and randomly change their values (independenty). So if $b_j$ is one of those $x$ elements, then the probability that its value is 0 is $1/2$ and the probability that its value if 1 is $1/2$ after modifying.

  **We choose $x'<m'$ elements and randomly change their values (independenty). So if $b_j$ is one of those $x'$ elements, the probability that its value  is 0 is $1/16$ and the probability that its value is not 0 is $15/16$ after modifying.**
- After that I want to know what the probability is for having at least $q<m$ zeros in the modified elements.

  **After that I want to know what the probability is for having at least $q'<m'$ zeros in the modified elements.**

I need a method to calculate this probability $P(m,n,x,q)$.

**I need a method to calculate this probability $P'(m',n',x',q')$.**

- $m > 1000$
- $0<n<0.3m$
- $0<x<0.6m$
- $0.5m <q < m$

Any idea? Thanks a lot !

In addition: if a mathematical approach is not available, I will also accept any answer that contains a complete java or matlab code where I just can plug in $m,n,x$ and $q$ with output $P$.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Another question. Does randomness only comes out of the random change? Because if $b$ is not chosen at random, then the question depends on $b$.

Comment: Good point.  Lets suppose that it not depends on $b$,  so every match appears equiprobably.

Comment: I updated my question, now I think its more clear

Comment: I thought it was clear. Not anymore, sorry.

Comment: @zhoraster: Im not very good in transforming my practical problem into mathematical language. But I think now the question is clear enough, right?

Comment: Now it looks more like the original version (in fact, more clear than it was, but still with some ambiguity as explained in my first comment). However, I do not find such substantial modification of a question, especially having a bounty, a nice solution. The worst thing is that you have deleted the part concerning the "large scale behavior".

Comment: To clarify: you're looking for an answer of the form $P(n,m,x,q)$, right? When you change the $x$ elements, is each one set to 0 or 1 independently from all the rest and from its previous state?

Comment: @DanielWeissman: the answer to both question is yes. For example if $x=2$ and we choose $b_i$ and $b_j$ for being randomly changed we have for the following events that $p=1/4: (b_i=0, b_j=0) ;(b_i=0,  b_j=1);(b_i=1,  b_j=0);(b_i=1, b_j=1)\\$.  For $x=3$ we have $8$ possible outcomes with $p=1/8$ per outcome etc.

Comment: For the $q$ elements you have selected to change: are you saying that they are *replaced* with a 0 or 1 with equal probability; or that they are *flipped* or *left alone* with equal probability?

Comment: @MichaelGrant: the second option. Randomly changing the value of an element means that the value *could* be changed  or *could* remain the same with $p=1/2$ for both outcomes.

Comment: BTW If a mathematical approach is not available, I will also accept any answer that contains a complete java or matlab code where I just can plug in $m,n,x$ and $q$ with output $P$.

Comment: If the $x$ elements are chosen uniformly random (and independent of the other choices), then the probability of a $b_j$ to be zero is $\frac{2mn-nx+mx}{2m^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If if doesn't have to be exact, the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) will be easy to use.  If an individual bit is chosen to be flipped, it has $\frac nm$ chance of starting as a $1$ and $\frac {m-n}m$ chance of starting as a $0$.  It has $\frac n{2m}$ chance of changing from $1$ to $0, \frac {m-n}{2m}$ chance of changing from $0$ to $1$ and $\frac 12$ chance of not changing.  Your expected number of $1$'s after flipping is then $\mu=n+x(\frac{m-n}{2m}-\frac n{2m})=n+x\frac{m-2n}{2m}.$  The variance on the change of a single bit is $\frac 12$, so the standard deviation of the number of $1$ bits after flipping is $\sigma=\sqrt {x}/2$  Compare your $q$ to $\mu$ to see how many standard deviations different they are.  You can then look up the probability of being that far away in a [standard normal or z-score table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table).  Your programming language may well have a function for this.

Added for the hex problem:  the same approach works.  First compute the expected number of zeros after the perturbation.  You start with $n'$ zeros, on average $n'(1-\frac x{m'})$ will not be modified and $\frac x{16}$ of the modified digits will become zero, so $\mu=n'(1-\frac x{m'})+\frac x{16}$.  The average change of the number of zeros in one altered digit is $\frac 1{16}-\frac {n'}{m'}$ The variance on the change of a single bit is $\frac 1{16}\cdot \frac {15}{16}=\frac {15}{256}$.  The standard deviation is then $\sigma=\frac {15x'}4$

Comment: Wow, great creative approach. Very good.  Thank you very much

Comment: I think you made a small mistake with the symbols right?

Comment: @Appliedmathematician:  I had the $\mu$ in the wrong place.  Is that it?

Comment: Yes thanks!   .. ...

Comment: Can we just multiply all variables ($m,n,x,q$) by 4 if we actually have a sequence of hexadecimal values (as in 4 bits we can store a hexidecimal value)?

Comment: It depends on how you define the perturbation.  Are you just doing the same operation but storing four bits per hex digit?  It would be easier to follow the above and just know you have $m/4$ hex digits. Or are you perturbing the whole hex digit at once, like your earlier question?  You can still use this technique, but the analysis needs to be repeated because the number of bits that change per perturbation is more complicated.

Comment: I added the hexadecimal (actually my 'real' problem) part to my question in bold. What I want is to do  operations on a file of $m'>1000$ hexadecimal values (where a hexidecimal value is treated as a unit).

Comment: Thanks for your update. Actually in my problem we have $n'$ elements that don't have value 0 and $m'-n'$ values that do have value 0. But I guess that your answer is correct if we have $n'$ zeros and $m'-n'$ elements that dont have value 0

Comment: Another question: is there a reason that you use $x$ instead of $x'$ ?

Comment: Question 3: Is your s.d. calculation correct? It seems to be too low (I assume we miss an $x$ in the calculation.

Comment: Yes, I was missing a factor $x$, which I have added.  There could be a mistake in the variance calculation-I tried to get it right, but you could check it.

Comment: With $x$ you mean $x'$?

Comment: I thought better on the variance and have updated.